# How do projects create huge NFT collections?

Tags: nft, erc-721, meta-data

Working with ERC20 is simple, but when it comes to NFTs, how can I manage bigger collections?

For example I wanna launch a collection of 2k NFTs. The problems are:

To upload the 2k images (This is simple maybe I can do that).

The problematic part is:

To create 2k URI JSON files and paste each image link in each JSON file, along with the different image links the JSON files will have different attributes/traits. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON metadata is usually generated via a script when you create your images, assuming you randomly generate images based on your existing traits files.
Everything is done via a script. You don't manually do this as it will take forever.

Images/Metadata can be uploaded to your own host or to [IPFS](https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/what-is-ipfs/) where you can dynamically generate the path based on the token ID (eg ipfs://<IPFS_HASH>/<TOKEN_ID>.png)

You generate the images, host them, and then create the final JSON metadata file for each token ID, where you can just simply point to the link where you hosted the image, and the traits used.

Comment: Can you point  me to some code examples or services that allows metadata generation?

Comment: This article should give you a better understanding of how to do it 

https://www.quicknode.com/guides/other-chains/arbitrum-nova/how-to-create-a-10k-nft-collection#overview